# How to transfer pdf file correctly with socket programming in C#?

Tags: c#, sockets, pdf

I am transferring file via socket programming in C# with the code given below. But when I take pdf as input file, it is not received correctly. I have seen sent and received files in notepad, they are not same. 
I am not able to figure it out. any help appreciated !!!

> Server Code:

```
class ConnectionInfo
{
    public Socket Socket;
    public byte[] Buffer;
    public int client;
    public string fileName;
}

class Program
{

    static int chunkSize = 16 * 1024;
    static int chucksizeWithoutHeaderData = chunkSize - 8;
    static List<ConnectionInfo> list = new List<ConnectionInfo>();

    static Socket serverSocket;

    static int nClient = 0;


    static void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        ConnectionInfo info = new ConnectionInfo();
        info.Socket = serverSocket.EndAccept(result);
        info.Buffer = new byte[chunkSize * 4];
        Console.WriteLine("Client connected");
        nClient++;
        info.client = nClient;

        list.Add(info);

        info.Socket.BeginReceive(info.Buffer, 0, info.Buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallBack), info);

        serverSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), null);
    }

    static void ReceiveCallBack(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        ConnectionInfo info = result.AsyncState as ConnectionInfo;
        try
        {
            Int32 nSegmentNumber = BitConverter.ToInt32(info.Buffer, 0);
            Int32 nMaxSegment = BitConverter.ToInt32(info.Buffer, 4);

            string strFileName = string.Format(@"D:\xyz.pdf", info.client);

            //int bySize = info.Socket.EndReceive(result);
            int bySize = 0;
            try
            {
                bySize = info.Socket.EndReceive(result);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error from client {0}: {1}", info.client, ex.Message);
                return;
            }
            if (bySize <= 0)
            {
                return;
            }
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(strFileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Received segment {0} of {1} from client {2}", nSegmentNumber, nMaxSegment, info.client);
                fs.Position = fs.Length;
                fs.Write(info.Buffer, 8, bySize - 8);
                Console.Write("Content in FILE: " + Encoding.ASCII.GetString(info.Buffer));
                if (nSegmentNumber >= nMaxSegment)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Completed receipt from client {0}", info.client);
                }
            }
            info.Socket.BeginReceive(info.Buffer, 0, info.Buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallBack), info);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Server");
            IPAddress address = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"); //The IP address of the server
            IPEndPoint myEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(address, 6503);
            serverSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            serverSocket.Bind(myEndPoint);

            serverSocket.Listen(1000);

            Console.WriteLine("Press enter to end server");
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

}
```

> Client code:

```
class Program
{
    static TcpClient socket = new TcpClient();
    static int chunkSize = 16 * 1024;
    static int chucksizeWithoutHeaderData = chunkSize - 8;
    static byte[] byReceiveBuffer = new byte[chunkSize * 4];
    static void ReceiveCallBack(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        Socket socket = result.AsyncState as Socket;
        try
        {
            int bySize = socket.EndReceive(result);

            Console.WriteLine("Recieved bytes {0}", bySize);

            if (bySize != 0)
            {
                Int32 nSegmentNumber = BitConverter.ToInt32(byReceiveBuffer, 0);
                Int32 nMaxSegment = BitConverter.ToInt32(byReceiveBuffer, 4);

                Console.WriteLine("Received segment {0} of {1}", nSegmentNumber, nMaxSegment);

                string strFileName = string.Format(@"c:\temp\client-from-server.dat");
                using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(strFileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
                {
                    fs.Position = fs.Length;
                    fs.Write(byReceiveBuffer, 8, bySize - 8);
                }

                if (nSegmentNumber >= nMaxSegment)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("all done");
                }
            }


            socket.BeginReceive(byReceiveBuffer, 0, byReceiveBuffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallBack), socket);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Press enter to go");
        Console.ReadLine();
        socket.Connect("127.0.0.1", 6503);

        Console.WriteLine("Client");
        Console.ReadLine();

        string filePath = "";
        string fileName = "C:\\abc.pdf";
        //fileName = fileName.Replace("\\", "/");
        while (fileName.IndexOf("\\") > -1)
        {
            filePath += fileName.Substring(0, fileName.IndexOf("\\") + 1);
            fileName = fileName.Substring(fileName.IndexOf("\\") + 1);
        }

        byte[] byBuffer;

        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@filePath+fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None))
        {

            using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs))
            {
                int nMaxChunk = 0;
                int nCurrentChunk = 0;
                nMaxChunk = (int)(fs.Length / chucksizeWithoutHeaderData);
                if ((nMaxChunk * chucksizeWithoutHeaderData) < fs.Length)
                {
                    ++nMaxChunk;
                }

                byte[] byMaxChunk = BitConverter.GetBytes(nMaxChunk);

                Int64 nAmount = 0;

                while (fs.Length > nAmount)
                {
                    ++nCurrentChunk;
                    byte[] byCurrentChunk = BitConverter.GetBytes(nCurrentChunk);

                    byBuffer = br.ReadBytes(chucksizeWithoutHeaderData);
                    Console.WriteLine("Sending {0}bytes, chunk {1} of {2}", byBuffer.Length, nCurrentChunk, nMaxChunk);

                    byte[] byTransmitBuffer = new byte[byBuffer.Length + 8];
                    Array.Copy(byCurrentChunk, byTransmitBuffer, 4);
                    Array.Copy(byMaxChunk, 0, byTransmitBuffer, 4, 4);
                    Array.Copy(byBuffer, 0, byTransmitBuffer, 8, byBuffer.Length);

                    socket.Client.Send(byTransmitBuffer);
                    nAmount += byBuffer.Length;
                }
            }
        }
        socket.Client.Disconnect(false);
        Console.WriteLine("done");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: When you compared the original and transmitted files, what sort of differences did you find?

Comment: If you want send files via Socket take a [look here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a0040ee8-227f-4d3c-a449-d0034a303163/send-and-receive-file-using-systemnetsocketssocket-in-c?forum=ncl)

Comment: Note, that you send the data to the server in 'chunksize'd chunks, each chunk having an 8-byte header. However, on the server - more specifcally at **info.Socket.BeginReceive** - you specify the receive buffer with a size of 4*chunksize. In the receive callback, you treat that '4*chunksize'd receive buffer as a single chunk, although it is in reality 4 chunks. That means, the PDF file data written on the server will erraneously also contain the 8-byte headers of each 2nd,3rd,4th chunk. (I hope i made no mistake reading your code...)

Comment: @Jongware the received file was having a litter more size then transmitted and some of the lines/bytes were added otherwise it was almost same.

Comment: Please try to be more specific than "*some* of the bytes". Is it perhaps a CR/LF issue? Do you get random bytes added? After every *n* bytes, or at random positions?

Comment: @Jongware if there is **‘tinyos.sh’** in transmitted file then it will be **â€˜tinyos.shâ€™** in received file. the problem is for special character transmission. I think that is the reason why pdf file is not correctly received.

Comment: You have a code page character translation problem. The weird characters you show are UTF-8 codes for the curly quotes.

Comment: @Jongware I tried BinaryWriter for writing into the file and now the text part i am getting correctly but still if transmitted file contains image then the image is distorted.